# Selenium returns wrong element when search by class/xpath/css

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to make simple python script that finds non-faded elements on site and click them.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(r"C:/Users/Dan/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/q3fhuchn.QAtest")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(ffprofile)

driver.get("https://www.steamgifts.com/giveaways/search?page=1&type=wishlist")
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("giveaway__row-inner-wrap")
element.find_element_by_class_name("giveaway__heading__name").click()
```

In this script Selenium returns wrong element with the similar class name - "giveaway__row-inner-wrap is-faded".

I've tried xpath and css selectors, but result was the same.
It looks like Selenium searches not the exact class name, but the one which contains search query.

Also script works fine with the following expression:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='giveaway__row-in‌​ner-wrap']//a[@class‌​='giveaway__heading_‌​_name']").click()
```

But I need list of all elements to be able to iterate them.

Here is example of both types of HTML elements:

```
    <div class="giveaway__row-outer-wrap" data-game-id="707524220">
        <div class="giveaway__row-inner-wrap is-faded">
            <div class="giveaway__summary">
                <h2 class="giveaway__heading">
                    <a class="giveaway__heading__name" href="/giveaway/FFdQd/call-of-duty-black-ops-iii-multiplayer-starter-pack">Call of Duty: Black Ops III - Multiplaye...</a><span class="giveaway__heading__thin">(15P)</span><a class="giveaway__icon" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://store.steampowered.com/app/437350/"><i class="fa fa-steam"></i></a><i data-popup="popup--hide-games" class="giveaway__icon giveaway__hide trigger-popup fa fa-eye-slash"></i>
                </h2>
                <div class="giveaway__columns">
                    <div><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <span title="Tomorrow, 4:59am">7 hours remaining</span></div><div class="giveaway__column--width-fill text-right"><span title="September 12, 2016, 4:01am">5 days ago</span> by <a class="giveaway__username" href="/user/Clockknight">Clockknight</a></div></div>
                    <div class="giveaway__links">
                        <a href="/giveaway/FFdQd/call-of-duty-black-ops-iii-multiplayer-starter-pack/entries"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> <span>2,552 entries</span></a>
                        <a href="/giveaway/FFdQd/call-of-duty-black-ops-iii-multiplayer-starter-pack/comments"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> <span>25 comments</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div><a href="/user/Clockknight" class="global__image-outer-wrap global__image-outer-wrap--avatar-small"><div class="global__image-inner-wrap" style="background-image:url(https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/51/5127d377a5bb8ee65356bcd81e44873824a2e7b5_medium.jpg);"></div></a><a class="global__image-outer-wrap global__image-outer-wrap--game-medium" href="/giveaway/FFdQd/call-of-duty-black-ops-iii-multiplayer-starter-pack"><div class="global__image-inner-wrap" style="background-image:url(https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/437350/capsule_184x69.jpg);"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="giveaway__row-outer-wrap" data-game-id="8668">
        <div class="giveaway__row-inner-wrap">
            <div class="giveaway__summary">
                <h2 class="giveaway__heading">
                    <a class="giveaway__heading__name" href="/giveaway/MsP6N/chaos-on-deponia">Chaos on Deponia</a><span class="giveaway__heading__thin">(100P)</span><a class="giveaway__icon" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://store.steampowered.com/app/220740/"><i class="fa fa-steam"></i></a><i data-popup="popup--hide-games" class="giveaway__icon giveaway__hide trigger-popup fa fa-eye-slash"></i>
                </h2>
                <div class="giveaway__columns">
                    <div><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <span title="Tomorrow, 7:00am">9 hours remaining</span></div><div class="giveaway__column--width-fill text-right"><span title="Today, 5:03pm">4 hours ago</span> by <a class="giveaway__username" href="/user/JsxfT">JsxfT</a></div></div>
                    <div class="giveaway__links">
                        <a href="/giveaway/MsP6N/chaos-on-deponia/entries"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> <span>84 entries</span></a>
                        <a href="/giveaway/MsP6N/chaos-on-deponia/comments"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> <span>0 comments</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div><a href="/user/JsxfT" class="global__image-outer-wrap global__image-outer-wrap--avatar-small"><div class="global__image-inner-wrap" style="background-image:url(https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/90/90b441d2627716a1a4c6be1f8fb375bea590c763_medium.jpg);"></div></a><a class="global__image-outer-wrap global__image-outer-wrap--game-medium" href="/giveaway/MsP6N/chaos-on-deponia"><div class="global__image-inner-wrap" style="background-image:url(https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/220740/capsule_184x69.jpg);"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I would be appreciate if someone can help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is correct. The element

```
<div class="giveaway__row-inner-wrap is-faded">
```

has in fact two classes: `giveaway__row-inner-wrap` and `is-faded` therefore it's correct that Selenium returns it. I suspect that you have two elements in that list, you just need to iterate it and locate the one element that does *not* also have the `is-faded` class.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this is the problem. It's strange that it was working previously, but looks like I need to rewrite code to exclude elements with the 'is-faded' class inside.

Comment: It might have worked previously because there was only one such `div` or for some reason it was returned as the first in the list.

Comment: I've found that script previously worked with following expression - **driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='giveaway__row-inner-wrap']//a[@class='giveaway__heading__name']").click()**  It also works fine now. Do you know why it selects only non-faded element?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to click on required element using `XPath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="giveaway__heading__name"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but this string works perfectly for my scenario, so I use it to create a list of non-faded elements:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='giveaway__row-inner-wrap']//a[@class='giveaway__heading__name']")
elements[x].click()
```